# Error 5 Unable to copy file " log.ldf" to "bin\log.ldf". The process cannot access the file as it is used by other process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I recently installed MS SQL Server 2012. I thought it would be a great database software.
But after 2 days trail, I found it is not that good as what I thought.

As you can see, every time when I run my project from VS 2010, VS always complains of the .ldf file is being used by another process.(which is the SQL Server 2012)
And then I have to disable the SQL Server service from the Service in the Computer Management, so the program can be compiled successfully.

But when the project is running, it requires the SQL Server service running, as some code needs to get access to the database and modify data.
Then I have to enable the SQL service.

It's really annoying. 
It didn't perform like this when I was using SQL Server 2008.

So are there any possible solutions?

I did try to add a configuration fragment in my web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And then I clean the whole solution and rebuild the whole solution,
errors remain.

I'm desperately looking forward to see the solutions asap.

Comment: Why your VS solution is trying to use (move/copy) the LDF file? Have you added the file to the solution flagging the Copy to output directory?

Comment: Oh my gosh, dear @Steve, you just saved my life and time. I spent almost a whole night to search and try those obscure articles and odd solutions, but none of them could solve this problem. You are genius! But I cannot adopt your comment as the solution, so do you mind to post it as a solution so I can mark your post as the right and brilliant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your solution contains a reference to the LDF file.
And by mistake the `Copy to the Output` directory is flagged as `Copy always` or `Copy if Newer`.

Of course the LDF file (log file) is constantly in use by SQL Server and therefore you get the described error when you compile.

You don't need to have a reference to this file so you can remove from the solution of flag as `Copy Never`.